# How to mention a user in GitHub wiki?

Tags: github

I tried to type `@username` in a github wiki page but it didn't generate any link. Is there any way to do it without manually linking to a user's profile?

Answer (score 10):

I think the only way to mention someone is :-
[@username] (https://www.github.com/username)

Answer (score 3):

They never provided the support for this and most probably never will. 
They have closed the issue ages ago. - https://github.com/github/markup/issues/209

> Advantages:
>
> - Mentioning users in a README allows readers to immediately view the user, via click or hover over, which is very convenient
> - as consequence, user mentions will be used more often, making users more interconnected.

> Disadvantages:
>
> - @username mentions cannot be clicked outside GitHub ([@username](https://github.com/username can be clicked).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly mention users using "@username". However, you can include links to their profiles in your README.md file like this:

`[Purna Shrestha](https://github.com/purnasth)`
or
`<a href="https://github.com/purnasth" target="_blank">Purna Shrestha</a>`